# Google Appengine + Jinja2: Output different templates depending on 'user role'

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I would like to output different templates for the front page of my webapp depending on the role of the logged in user.

I have two types of '*Accounts*' structured using the *PolyModel* data model:

```
class Account(polymodel.PolyModel):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)

class Farmer(Account):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)

class FarmCompany(Account):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

The app's homepage ('/') is *index.html* which inherits from *base.html* using *jinja2*:

**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Farmers App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}  
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

Now, because I've used the PolyModel data structure, the each 'Account' entity is stored as the following:

**Farmer 'Account' Entity example:**

```
Farmer(
    key=Key('Account', 5066549580791808), 
    class_=[u'Account', u'SkilledPerson'],
    name=u'Haopei', ...)
```

**FarmCompany 'Account' Entity example:**

```
FarmCompany(
    key=Key('Account', 6863449581091834), 
    class_=[u'Account', u'FarmCompany'],  
    name=u'Big Farm Company', ...)
```

This means I can get the Account type with a function like this:

```
def check_user_role_by_uid(self, uid):
    user = Account.get_by_id(uid)
    return user.class_[1] #returns 'Farmer' or 'FarmCompany'
```

**So my question is:**

How do I create two separate 'index.html' to be used depending on whether the logged in user is a 'Farmer' or a 'FarmCompany'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create two separate versions of index.html.  Let's call them index_farm.html and index_farmcompany.html.

Then in your handler, you'd use the appropriate version:

```
class myHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
    def get(self):
        # somehow get account uiod
        type =  Account.check_user_role_by_uid(uid)
        if type == 'SkilledPerson':
            self.render('index_farm.html')
        elif type == 'FarmCompany':
            self.render('index_farmcompany.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach: In python you can send `account_type` as a parameter. For example:

```
 return {'account': check_user_role_by_uid(uid)}
```

With jinja2 you can select the correct template, reuse HTML and add particular code for each account. If afterwards you have more accounts, it's easier to extend

```
index.html
{% if account == 'Farmer' %}
  {% extends "farmer_base.html" %} {# you can extend from different base #}
{% else %}
  {% extends "farmcompany_base.html" %}
{% endif %}

{% block content %}
    {{ content }}
    {% if account == 'Farmer' %}
      {# Some Farmer stuff #} {# or you can add particular code for an account #}
     {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```